# SSH into AWS EC2 without copy/pasting DNS each time

Tags: ssh, amazon-web-services, amazon-ec2

Following generation of a PEM file, and starting the instance, logging in requires copying the public DNS each time you wish to SSH in ([as shown in AWS docs](https://docs.aws.amazon.com/AWSEC2/latest/UserGuide/AccessingInstancesLinux.html)):

```
ssh -i /path/my-key-pair.pem my-instance-user-name@my-instance-public-dns-name
```

However, for instances that start and stop a lot, it requires copy and pasting the new DNS that's assigned at each instantace start. Is there a way to SSH-in without having to copy the new public DNS from the AWS console each time there is an instance start/stop? Like using a fixed DNS or something?

Answer (score 0):

You can use an Elastic IP (EIP) address then ssh using the EIP